# Lambda as apply function for dask dataframe

Tags: dask

I am trying to use lambdas as function to apply to a dask dataframe in a for loop creating a list of dask dataframe.
When I compute each dataframe, they all use the last lambda expression instead of the one asigned during the loop.

Example:

```
ddf = dataframe.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame([[1, 10],[1, 5],[2, 9],[2, 4]], 
columns=['group', 'value']), npartitions=2)
ddfs = []
for val in [2, 100]:
    ddfs.append(ddf.groupby('group').apply(lambda x : x.sum()+val))
```

Output:

```
ddfs[0].compute()

group   value   
2   104 113
1   102 115

ddfs[1].compute()

group   value   
2   104 113
1   102 115
```

I would think that they are not supposed to be the same the first is supposed to be

```
group   value   
2   6   15
1   4   17
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scoping problem with python itself. When the function is executed, it looks for the value of `val` in the global scope, it is *not* bound in the function closure.

To fix, you need to use an optional keyword parameter, which is evaluated at declaration time, and so bound:

```
for val in [2, 100]:
   ddfs.append(ddf.groupby('group').apply(lambda x, val=val: x.sum()+val))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Didn't know about the keyword parameter in lambda function